# Google Big Query Quickest Way to save locally

Tags: google-bigquery

currently my code is as follows:

```
query_job = bqClient.query(query)
iterator = query_job.result(timeout=600)
rows = list(iterator)
df =  pd.DataFrame(data=[list(x.values()) for x in rows], columns=list(rows[0].keys()))
df.to_csv("x.csv")
```

Is there a way to directly save the iterator as a csv? Doing what I am doing over millions of rows is a bit slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to you question, you problem is related to performance. Therefore, I would like to ask atention for your last line of code for the method ***to_csv***. It has some optional parameters which can be useful in your case, I would suggest for you to use ***chunksize***. This parameter defines the amount of rows it writes at a time, you can read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). If you want you can also have a look at *line 1555* which shows how this parameter is set to 1 when it is not defined, which can cause less performance. Lastly, I would encourage you to have a look on the "mode" parameter, which can be also found in the above documentation, each mode of classification is described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html).

As a bonus information, I would like to suggest that you can also use [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/) with a Pub/Sub & StackDriver Trigger and BigQuery to save your *.csv* file to Cloud Storage.